# Find a node that does not contain an attribute?

Tags: xml, xquery, xml-attribute

The creator of an XML document that I'm running XQuery commands on left the `lang` attribute out of titles in titled sales materials (books, records, CD's, etc.) that are in English, making it difficult to locate English titles.  I'm looking for a way to locate results that do not contain an `xml:lang` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use just**:

```
//title[not(@xml:lang)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a where clause containing the `not()` function, to limit your results:

```
for $resulta in doc("test")//catalog/item/title
where $resulta[not(@xml:lang)] (: this line :)
return $resulta
```